# Making an image not displace other images in HTML

Tags: html

I have a website where I want an piece of text to be covered up unless the user clicks on it, but when I try to place the image on top of the text it causes it to wrap around the image, any ideas on how to make the image in the background and not displace anything?

Code:

```
<img src="http://i980.photobucket.com/albums/ae282/Omnilord97/Transparent.png" 
     width="250" height="450" alt="photo Transparent.png" align="middle">
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: What @DanielStanley is trying to say (and not doing it very well) is that we would appreciate seeing some code, or if possible please replicate your issue using http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thank-you @freefaller for expanding on my comment for me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/un4rcvj3/

Answer (score 0):

Make it a background image and show/hide a div inside of it. Here it is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m05dhpvb/)

HTML

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="text">
        This is the text to show
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*--Original Background Image or Color--*/
.image {
    background:red; /*-- For image bg use: url('http://example.com/image.jpg'); --*/
    width:250px;
    height:450px;
}

/*--New Background Image or Color--*/
.image.showText {
    background:#ececec; /*-- For image bg use: url('http://example.com/image.jpg'); --*/
}

.image .text {
    display:none;
    padding:20px;
}

.image.showText .text {
    display:block;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".image").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("showText");
});
```